# My child component checkbox is not updating when props changed from the parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

This is the code from my parent component TodoList:

```
_handleSelectedTodo(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.setState({checkedIds: [...this.state.checkedIds, e.target.value]});
  }
//render() { ...
  <ul>
    {todos.map((todo,todoIndex) => 
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo} // pass all the todo property
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
        onTrashClick={() => onDeleteClick(todoIndex)}
        handleSelectedTodo = {this._handleSelectedTodo}
        checked={(this.state.checkedIds.includes(todo.id))}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
```

when the checkbox in Todo component is checked I add checkedIds on the state of TodoList Component. You can see on the checked prop on todo that I use includes to set it to true or false. But my problem is my child component doesn't update and I am using componentWillReceiveProps. This is the code:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= { checked: false }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({ checked: nextProps.checked });  
}
// render() { ...
<input
   checked={this.state.checked}
   onChange={handleSelectedTodo}
   type="checkbox"
   value={id}
></input>
```

It's all working and when clicked the checked is true on React debugger but it will not rerender, it only rerender if I check another box, the last one I checked will be checked and not the latest one?

Comment: Yes, I tried using props directly but it's not still updating. it's updating on my React debugger but it will not be checked, once I checked another checkbox that's when the last one checked will rerender and not the latest checkbox I attempt to check

Comment: `onChange={handleSelectedTodo}` in your child component.  Shouldn't this be `onChange={this.props.handleSelectedTodo}`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `()` around `this.state.checkedIds.includes(todo.id)`.

```
//render() { ...
  <ul>
    {todos.map((todo,todoIndex) => 
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo} // pass all the todo property
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
        onTrashClick={() => onDeleteClick(todoIndex)}
        handleSelectedTodo = {this._handleSelectedTodo}
        checked={this.state.checkedIds.includes(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
```

Comment: I think it has to do with the delay in rendering from passing the value to the component's state via a new lifecycle. Having the extra parenthesis shouldn't really effect whether or not the reconciliation algorithm determines to rerender the input component.

Comment: What's included when you destructure `{...todo}`? Are you possibly setting `checked` there?

Comment: no, just the properties of the todo to be pass as props on Todo component

Comment: @MichaelLyons any delay shouldn't matter, once new props come into the component it will trigger a rerender unless stopped in a `shouldComponentUpdate` function.

Comment: I am wondering because on the debugger it's all working perfectly, checked has value of true but not checked. until I attempt to check another box, but the latest checkbox I want will not be checked @ChaseDeAnda

Comment: Okay, try to set your state like this in the constructor: `this.state = { checked: props.checked }`. You may be destroying the component on each rerender which sets the checked state to `false` by default.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda True. I guess I'd want to see more about how ```_handleSelectedTodo``` is implemented and how ```this.state.checkedIds``` is updated.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda same thing, checked is true on debugger but not re rendered so it's not checked, same issue

Comment: @MichaelLyons I have to accept you comment, I was using preventDefault() missed it for hours :/

Comment: @iamnewbie so did you remove preventDefault and it started updating properly? Or is it still not updating in sync?

Comment: @MichaelLyons yes, removed preventDefault, I was used to it, and I missed it. thank u